# Formatting data sheet datetime values with pandas and numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, datetime

The code below calculates the  `mean','median','max','min'`  of the  `vals`  values that are in correlation to the dates  `month_changes` . The code calculates the  `mean','median','max','min'`  by separating the intervals in years. I want to implement a bit to the code where it adds zeroes to the  `mean','median','max','min'` values for the years that start from the  `starting_year`  variable, also to the years that are in between one another like 2020 in this example it will also add zeroes. How would I be able to do that?

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

month_changes = np.array(["2018-04-01 00:00:00", "2018-05-01 00:00:00", "2019-03-01 00:00:00", "2019-04-01 00:00:00","2019-08-01 00:00:00", "2019-11-01 00:00:00", "2019-12-01 00:00:00","2021-01-01 00:00:00"]) 
vals = np.array([10, 23, 45, 4,5,12,4,-6])
starting_year = 2016

def YearlyIntervals(vals):
    data = pd.DataFrame({"Date": month_changes, "Averages": vals})
    data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"])
    out=(data.groupby(data["Date"].dt.year)
         .agg(['mean','median','max','min'])
         .droplevel(0,1)
         .rename(columns=lambda x:'Average' if x=='mean' else x.title())
        )
    return out

PnL_YearlyFilter= YearlyIntervals(vals)
```

Output

```
          Average     Median    Max  Min 
Date                                                                         
2018      16.5        16.5      23   10
2019      14.0        5.0       45    4 
2021      -6.0       -6.0       -6   -6
```

Expected Output

```
          Average     Median    Max  Min 
Date
2016      0           0         0     0
2017      0           0         0     0
2018      16.5        16.5      23   10
2019      14.0        5.0       45    4
2020      0           0         0     0
2021      -6.0       -6.0       -6   -6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with a `fill_value=0`.

One way it can be added to the function is like:

```
def yearly_intervals(mc, vs, start_year=None, end_year=None):
    data = pd.DataFrame({
        "Date": pd.to_datetime(mc),  # Convert to_datetime immediately
        "Averages": vs
    })
    out = (
        data.groupby(data["Date"].dt.year)["Averages"]  # Access Series
            .agg(['mean', 'median', 'max', 'min'])
            .rename(columns=lambda x: 'Average' if x == 'mean' else x.title())
    )
    # If start_year
    if start_year is not None:
        # Reindex to ensure index contains all years in range
        out = out.reindex(range(
            start_year,
            # Use last year (maximum value) from index or user defined arg
            (end_year if end_year is not None else out.index.max()) + 1
        ), fill_value=0)
    return out
```

Some changes made:

1. PEP8 guidelines state that function names should "should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary". [Function and Variable Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names)
2. The numpy array can be converted directly [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) when building the DataFrame without needing to build the DataFrame then convert the Series afterwards.
3. Slight modifications to the groupby aggregation using [`SeriesGroupBy.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html) instead of DataFrame groupby to ensure more consistent behaviour across versions.
4. `start_year` and `end_year` kwargs with default parameters allow for more flexibility of the function so that any range of years can be used. (More argument processing could be added to ensure that `end_year` is always larger than `start_year`)
5. `end_year` is optional. If no `end_year` is provided it will use the [`Index.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.max.html) (the largest value in the index)

---

Sample function call:

```
month_changes = np.array(
    ["2018-04-01 00:00:00", "2018-05-01 00:00:00", "2019-03-01 00:00:00",
     "2019-04-01 00:00:00", "2019-08-01 00:00:00", "2019-11-01 00:00:00",
     "2019-12-01 00:00:00", "2021-01-01 00:00:00"])
vals = np.array([10, 23, 45, 4, 5, 12, 4, -6])
starting_year = 2016

PnL_YearlyFilter = yearly_intervals(month_changes, vals, starting_year)
```

`PnL_YearlyFilter`:

```
      Average  Median  Max  Min
Date                           
2016      0.0     0.0    0    0
2017      0.0     0.0    0    0
2018     16.5    16.5   23   10
2019     14.0     5.0   45    4
2020      0.0     0.0    0    0
2021     -6.0    -6.0   -6   -6
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer could you also take a look at this issue, it revolves around this issue as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69202580/combining-multiple-datasheets-with-pandas-python