# Combining multiple datasheets with Pandas Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, datetime

The code below calculates the  `mean','median','max','min'`  of the  `vals`  values that are in correlation to the dates  `month_changes` . The code calculates the  `mean','median','max','min'`  by separating the intervals in years. I want to implement a bit to the code where it adds zeroes to the  `mean','median','max','min'` values for the years that start from the  `starting_year`  variable. I am trying to combine both of the datasheets together with the `join()` but it is not working. How would I be able to do that? In the Expected Output I want to have a single `Date` column.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

month_changes = np.array(["2018-04-01 00:00:00", "2018-05-01 00:00:00", "2019-03-01 00:00:00", "2019-04-01 00:00:00","2019-08-01 00:00:00", "2019-11-01 00:00:00", "2019-12-01 00:00:00","2021-01-01 00:00:00"])
vals = np.array([10, 23, 45, 4,5,12,4,-6])

month_changes_2 = np.array(["2018-04-06 00:00:00", "2018-05-13 00:00:00", "2018-03-01 00:00:00", "2019-02-01 00:00:00","2019-03-12 00:00:00", "2019-12-01 00:00:00", "2019-12-22 00:00:00","2020-04-01 00:00:00","2021-01-01 00:00:00"])
vals_2 = np.array([140, 213, 15, 4,53,1,42,-63,120])

list_val = ['mean', 'median', 'max', 'min']

#print(list_val[:2])
def years(): 
    def yearly_intervals(mc, vs, start_year, end_year, series_val, print_type):
        #print(series_val)
        data = pd.DataFrame({
            "Date": pd.to_datetime(mc),  # Convert to_datetime immediately
            "Averages": vs
        })
        out = (
            data.groupby(data["Date"].dt.year)["Averages"]  # Access Series
                .agg(list_val[series_val[0]:series_val[-1]])
                .rename(columns=lambda x: f'{print_type} Average' if x == 'mean' else x.title())
                .rename(columns=lambda x: f'{print_type} Median' if x == 'Median' else x.title())
                .rename(columns=lambda x: f'{print_type} Median' if x == 'Max' else x.title())
                .rename(columns=lambda x: f'{print_type} Median' if x == 'Min' else x.title())
        )
        # If start_year
        if start_year is not None:
            # Reindex to ensure index contains all years in range
            out = out.reindex(range(
                start_year,
                # Use last year (maximum value) from index or user defined arg
                (end_year if end_year is not None else out.index.max()) + 1
            ), fill_value=0)
        print(out)
        return out

    graph= yearly_intervals(month_changes, vals, start_year=2016, end_year=2021,series_val=[0,2],print_type = 'Month 1')
    graph_2= yearly_intervals(month_changes_2, vals_2, start_year=2016, end_year=2021,series_val = [0,4], print_type = 'Month 2')
    graph.join(graph_2)
    return graph 

result = years()
```

Output:

```
      Month 1 Average  Month 1 Median
Date                                 
2016              0.0             0.0
2017              0.0             0.0
2018             16.5            16.5
2019             14.0             5.0
2020              0.0             0.0
2021             -6.0            -6.0
```

Expected Output:

```
      Month 1 Average  Month 1 Median  Month 2 Average  Month 2 Median  Month 2 Median  Month 2 Median
Date                                 
2016              0.0             0.0        0.000000               0               0               0
2017              0.0             0.0        0.000000               0               0               0
2018             16.5            16.5      122.666667             140             213              15
2019             14.0             5.0       25.000000              23              53               1
2020              0.0             0.0      -63.000000             -63             -63             -63
2021             -6.0            -6.0      120.000000             120             120             120
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand this is what might give you the intended result: Merging the two datasets with an outer join and than replacing the resulting NaN with fillna(...)

**Edit**

In your code you are missing to assign the result of pandas `join()` to a variable, the function is returning a new dataset, so you could change it e.g. to `return graph.join(graph_2)`

Comment: sorry I couldnt really comprehend what you are saying there are no Nan values,  empty values are zeroes